# Why does "int[] is uint[] == true" in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, casting, unsigned

Can somebody clarify the C# `is` keyword please. In particular these 2 questions:

Q1) line 5; Why does this return true?

Q2) line 7; Why no cast exception?

```
public void Test()
{
    object intArray = new int[] { -100, -200 };            

    if (intArray is uint[]) //why does this return true?
    {
        uint[] uintArray = (uint[])intArray; //why no class cast exception?

        for (int x = 0; x < uintArray.Length; x++)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(uintArray[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

MSDN's description does not clarify the situation. It states that `is` will return true if either of these conditions are met. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(VS.71).aspx>MDSN Article)

```
expression is not null.
expression can be cast to type.
```

I don't believe that you can do a valid cast of int[] into uint[]. Because:

A) This code does not compile:

```
int[] signed = new int[] { -100 };
uint[] unsigned = (uint[])signed;
```

B) Doing the cast in the debugger gives an error:

```
(uint[])signed
"Cannot convert type 'int[]' to 'uint[]'"
```

Sure enough, if line 3 was int[] instead of object then it would never compile. Which brings me to a final question related to Q2.

Q3) Why does C# raise a cast/conversion error in the debugger and compiler but not at runtime?

Comment: Where is Eric Lippert when you need him?

Comment: Wrong, this is Stack Overflow, you mean "Where is Jon Skeet when you need him?" ;)

Comment: Check my answer, I updated with a link to a video which I think explains the underlying issue. Check it out!

Comment: Eric Lippert is here: [why-does-my-c-sharp-array-lose-type-sign-information-when-cast-to-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178973/why-does-my-c-sharp-array-lose-type-sign-information-when-cast-to-object/1179094#1179094)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my C# array lose type sign information when cast to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178973/why-does-my-c-sharp-array-lose-type-sign-information-when-cast-to-object)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

C# and the CLR have somewhat different conversion rules.

You can't *directly* cast between `int[]` and `uint[]` in C# because the *language* doesn't believe any conversion is available. However, if you go via `object` the result is up to the CLI. From the CLI spec section 8.7 (I hope - I'm quoting an [email exchange I had on this topic with Eric Lippert](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/2d21bf036a23918e#5a5c351206ebd999) a while ago):

> Signed and unsigned integral primitive
>   types can be assigned to each other;
>   e.g., int8 := uint8 is valid. For this
>   purpose, bool shall be considered
>   compatible with `uint8` and vice versa,
>   which makes `bool := uint8` valid, and
>   vice versa. This is also true for
>   arrays of signed and unsigned integral
>   primitive types of the same size;
>   e.g., `int32[] := uint32[]` is valid.

(I haven't checked, but I assume that this sort of reference type conversion being valid is what makes `is` return true as well.)

It's somewhat unfortunate that there are disconnects between the language and the underlying execution engine, but it's pretty much unavoidable in the long run, I suspect. There are a few other cases like this, but the good news is that they rarely seem to cause significant harm.

EDIT: As Marc deleted his answer, I've linked to the full mail from Eric, as posted to the C# newsgroup.

Comment: sounds like another candidate for the "what can you do in MSIL you can't in c#" question. direct convesion without having to messabout with an object/Array variable to placate the c# compiler

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk: Good call - will update my answer, linking to this question.

Comment: Doesn't sound much type-safe to me.

Answer (score 4):

Now that's interesting. I found this in the ECMA-335 standard. 4.3 castclass. Note that:

- Arrays inherit from System.Array.
- If Foo can be cast to Bar, then Foo[] can be cast to Bar[].
- For the purposes of note 2 above, enums are treated as their underlying type: thus E1[] can be cast to E2[] if E1 and E2 share an underlying type.

You can cast int to uint, but that it behaves like this is very strange. Visual Studio does not recognize any of this, even the watch, when the debugger is attached just shows a question mark '?'.

**You might wanna take a look at [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Expert-to-Expert-Anders-Hejlsberg-The-Future-of-C/), fast forward about 10 minutes in and listen to Anders explain the co-variant array implementation. I think that is the fundamentally underlying issue here.**

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

Declaring intArray as "int [] intArray" rather then "object intArray" will allow the compiler to pick up the invalid C# cast.  Unless you absolutely have to use object, I would take that approach.

Re Q2,Q3:

At runtime have you tried wrapping the cast in a [checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) block?

From this article at MSDN:

> By default, an expression that
>   contains only constant values causes a
>   compiler error if the expression
>   produces a value that is outside the
>   range of the destination type. If the
>   expression contains one or more
>   non-constant values, the compiler does
>   not detect the overflow.
>
> ...
>
> By default, these non-constant
>   expressions are not checked for
>   overflow at run time either, and they
>   do not raise overflow exceptions. The
>   previous example displays
>   -2,147,483,639 as the sum of two positive integers.
>
> Overflow checking can be enabled by
>   compiler options, environment
>   configuration, or use of the checked
>   keyword.

As it says, you can enforce overflow checking more globally via a compiler setting or environment config.

In your case this is probably desirable as it will cause a runtime error to be thrown that will ensure the likely invalid unsigned number to signed number overflow will not occur silently.

[Update] After testing this code, I found that using a declaration of type object instead of int [] appears to bypass the standard C# casting sytax, regardless of whether checked is enabled or not.

As JS has said, when you use object, you are bound by CLI rules and these apparently allow this to occur.

Re Q1:

This is related to the above.  In short, because the cast involved it does not throw an exception (based on current overflow setting).  Whether this is a good idea is another question.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

> An "is" expression evaluates to true if the provided expression is non-null, and the
>   provided object can be cast to the provided type without causing an exception to be 
>   thrown.

Comment: But it does not answer his first question, "why does (intArray is uint[])"

Comment: Nope, checked doesn't catch this, surprisingly. The debugger is utterly confused by the contents (showing just ? for the elements in the inspector), and getting the value out gets the wrapped value.

Comment: Same behaviour in my test.  Where's Jon Skeet when you need him?

Comment: Down there. (probably soon to be up there :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing backwards compatablility with .NET 1: I'm still a bit fuzzy about the details, but I beleive the CLR type of all arrays is simply System.Array, with extra Type properties to lookup the element type. 'is' probably just didn't account for that in CLR v1, and now must maintain that.

It not working in the `(uint[])(new int[]{})` case is probably due to the C# compiler (not the CLR runtime) being able to do stricter typechecking.

Also, arrays are just type unsafe in general:

```
Animal[] tigers = new Tiger[10];
tigers[3] = new Elephant(); // ArrayTypeMismatchException
```

Answer (score 0):

OK,

I attempt to take a stab at this.

First off, the documentation says, "Checks if an object is compatible with a given type.", It also says that IF the type on the left is "castable" (you can convert without exception) to the type on the right, and the expression evaluates to non-null, the "is" keyword will evaluate to `true`.

Look to Jon Skeet for the other answer.  He said it more eloquently than I could.  He's right, if a conversion is available, it will accept your syntax, you could subsequently write your own, but it would seem overkill in this situation.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(VS.80).aspx