# convert an array of enums into a generic array of enums

Tags: c#, arrays, enums

How can I convert an array of enums into a generic array of enums in c#.

To be clear:

Given:

```
public enum PrimaryColor
{
    red = 0,
    blue = 1,
    yellow = 3
}

public enum SecondaryColor
{
    green = 0,
    purple = 1,
    orange = 2
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        PrimaryColor[] pca = {PrimaryColor.blue, PrimaryColor.yellow};
        SecondaryColor[] sca = {SecondaryColor.purple, SecondaryColor.orange};

        Enum[] enumArray = pca;
    }

}
```

which leads to a compiler error of:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'PrimaryColor[]' to 'System.Enum[]'
```

I could use linq or some more iterative process, but I wonder if there is a better cast I could use instead.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it iteratively only

```
Enum[] enumArray = Array.ConvertAll(pca, item => (Enum)item);
```

Or (less efficient but Linq!)

```
Enum[] enumArray = pca.Cast<Enum>().ToArray();
```

Why you can't simply cast arrays? Because in C# [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) enabled only for arrays of reference types (enums are value types). So, with class `Foo` you can do:

```
Foo[] foos = new Foo[10];
object[] array = (object[])foos;
```

Comment: An interesting oddity in the type system is that the CLR type system allows array covariance on compatible value types. For example, `uint[]` is convertible to `int[]`. C# as you correctly note only allows array covariance if both types are reference types. Which means that it is possible that in C#, the cast `(int[])(object)x` will succeed at runtime, but the same cast without `object` would fail at compile time.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks, great comment! Didn't know that array covariance on compatible value types is allowed. Btw why `Enum` does not considered compatible for example above? I.e. I can do `(int[])(object)pca`, but I can't do `(Enum[])(object)pca`. Also looks like there is a bug in VS2012 http://s4.postimage.org/c17b94me5/array_covariance.png :)

Comment: Enum is a reference type; it's a boxed enum. The array therefore has to be full of *references*, not full of *values*.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/24/why-is-covariance-of-value-typed-arrays-inconsistent.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178973/why-does-my-c-sharp-array-lose-type-sign-information-when-cast-to-object/1179094#1179094 for more details on how CLR variance differs from C# variance.

Answer (score 0):

```
PrimaryColor[] pca = { PrimaryColor.blue, PrimaryColor.yellow };
SecondaryColor[] sca = { SecondaryColor.purple, SecondaryColor.orange };

Enum[] enumArray = pca.Select(q => q as Enum).ToArray();
```

Or;

```
for (int i=0; i<pca.Count();i++)
{
    enumArray[i] = pca[i];                
}
```