# Type system oddity: Enumerable.Cast<int>()

Tags: c#, linq

Consider:

```
enum Foo
{
    Bar,
    Quux,
}

void Main()
{
    var enumValues = new[] { Foo.Bar, Foo.Quux, };
    Console.WriteLine(enumValues.GetType());         // output: Foo[]
    Console.WriteLine(enumValues.First().GetType()); // output: Foo

    var intValues = enumValues.Cast<int>();
    Console.WriteLine(intValues.GetType());         // output: Foo[] ???
    Console.WriteLine(intValues.First().GetType()); // output: Int32

    Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(enumValues, intValues)); // true

    var intValuesArray = intValues.ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(intValuesArray.GetType());         // output: Int32[]
    Console.WriteLine(intValuesArray.First().GetType()); // output: Int32

    Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(intValues, intValuesArray)); // false
}
```

Note the third `Console.WriteLine` - I'm expecting it to print the type to which the array is being cast (`Int32[]`), but instead it prints the original type (`Foo[]`)! And `ReferenceEquals` confirms that indeed, the first `Cast<int>` call is effectively a no-op.

So I peeked into the [source of `Enumerable.Cast`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,27bb217a6d5457ec) and found the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source) 
{
    IEnumerable<TResult> typedSource = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
    if (typedSource != null) return typedSource;
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    return CastIterator<TResult>(source);
}
```

For our intents and purposes, the only thing that matters are the first two lines, because they're the only ones that get called. That means that the line:

```
var intValues = enumValues.Cast<int>();
```

is effectively translated into:

```
var intValues = ((IEnumerable)enumValues) as IEnumerable<int>;
```

However, removing the cast to the non-generic `IEnumerable` causes a compiler error:

```
var intValues = enumValues as IEnumerable<int>; // error
```

I've been scratching my head as to why this is, and I *think* it's got to do with the fact that `Array` implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` and that there is all sorts of special casing for arrays in C#, but I'm honestly not sure. Please can someone explain to me what's going on here and why?

Comment: Well, ReSharper even complains that `((IEnumerable)enumValues) as IEnumerable<int>` would always be `null`, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: The special casting you talking about is covariance, the `IEnumerable<out t>`. It is actually not allowed to do this: `var intValues = enumValues as IEnumerable<int>;` it is well know. The thing why it prints Foo[] instead of `int` is because `int` is by default underlying type of the enum...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I think it's got to do with the fact that Array implements the non-generic IEnumerable and that there is all sorts of special casing for arrays in C#

Yes, you're correct. More precisely, it has to do with *array variance*. Array variance is a loosening of the type system that happened in .NET1.0 which was problematic but allowed for some tricky cases to be gotten around. Here's an example:

```
string[] first = {"a", "b", "c"};
object[] second = first;
string[] third = (string[])second;
Console.WriteLine(third[0]); // Prints "a"
```

This is quite weak because it doesn't stop us doing:

```
string[] first = {"a", "b", "c"};
object[] second = first;
Uri[] third = (Uri[])second; // InvalidCastException
```

And there are worse cases again.

It's less useful (if they ever were justified, which some would debate) now we have generics (from .NET2.0 and C#2 onwards) than before when it allowed us to overcome some of the limitations not having generics imposed on us.

The rules allow us do implicit casts to bases of reference types (e.g. `string[]` to `object[]`) explicit casts to derived reference types (e.g. `object[]` to `string[]`) and explicit casts from `Array` or `IEnumerable` to any type of array and also (this is the sticky part) `Array` and `IEnumerable` references to arrays of primitive types or enums can be cast to arrays of primitive types of enums of the same size (`int`, `uint` and `int`-based enums are all the same size).

This means that the attempted optimisation of not casting individual values unnecessarily when one can just cast the `source` directly can have the surprising effects you note.

A practical effect of this that has tripped me up in the past is if you were to try `enumValues.Cast<StringComparison>().ToArray()` or `enumValues.Cast<StringComparison>().ToList()`. These would fail with `ArrayTypeMismatchException` even though `enumValues.Cast<StringComparison>().Skip(0).ToArray()` would succeed, because as well as `Cast<TResult>()` using the optimisation noted, `ToArray<TSource>()` and `ToList<TSource>()` use optimisations of calling `ICollection<T>.CopyTo()` internally, and on arrays that fails with the sort of variance involved here.

In .NET Core there was a loosening of the restrictions on `CopyTo()` with arrays that means this code succeeds rather than throwing, but I forget at which version that change was introduced.

Answer (score 16):

Jon Hanna's answer is pretty much correct, but I can add a few small details.

> I'm expecting it to print the type to which the array is being cast `Int32[]`, but instead it prints the original type `Foo[]`!

What should you have expected? The contract of `Cast<int>` is that the object that is returned can be used in any context that expects an `IEnumerable<int>`, and you got that. That's all you should have expected; the rest is implementation details.

Now, I grant you that the fact that a `Foo[]` can be used as `IEnumerable<int>` is odd, but remember, a `Foo` is just an extremely thin wrapper around an `int`.  The size of a `Foo` is the same as the size of an `int`, the contents of a `Foo` are the same as the contents of an `int`, and so the CLR in its wisdom answers "yes" when asked "is this `Foo[]` usable as an `IEnumerable<int>`?"

But what about this?

> `enumValues as IEnumerable<int>`  causes a compiler error

This sure sounds like a contradiction, doesn't it?

The problem is that the rules of C# and the rules of the CLR do not match in this situation.

- The CLR says "a `Foo[]` can be used as an `int[]`, and a `uint[]` and ... ".
- The C# type analyzer is more restrictive. **It does not use all of the lax covariance rules of the CLR**. The C# type analyzer will allow `string[]` to be used as `object[]`, and will allow `IEnumerable<string>` to be used as `IEnumerable<object>` but it will not allow `Foo[]` to be used as `int[]` or `IEnumerable<int>` and so on.  **C# only allows covariance when the varying types are both reference types**.  The CLR allows covariance when the varying types are reference types, or `int`, `uint`, or `int`-sized enums.

The C# compiler "knows" that the conversion from `Foo[]` to `IEnumerable<int>` cannot succeed *in the C# type system*, and so it produces a compiler error; a conversion in C# must be *possible* to be legal.  The fact that this is possible in the more-lenient CLR type system is not considered by the compiler.

**By inserting a cast to `object` or `IEnumerable` or whatever, you are telling the C# compiler to stop using the rules of C#, and start letting the runtime figure it out.**  By removing the cast, you're saying that you want the C# compiler to render its judgment, and it does.

So now we have a language design problem; plainly we have an inconsistency here. There are several ways out of this inconsistency.

- C# could match the rules of the CLR, and allow covariant conversions amongst integer types.
- C# could generate the `as` operator so that it implements the rules of C# at runtime; basically, it would have to detect legal-in-the-CLR but illegal-in-C# conversions and disallow them, making all such conversions slower. Moreover, it would then require your scenario to go to the memory-allocating slow path of `Cast<T>` instead of the reference-preserving fast path.
- C# could be inconsistent and live with the inconsistency.

The second choice is obviously unfeasible. It only adds costs and has no benefits other than consistency.

It comes down then to the first and third choices, and the C# 1.0 design team chose the third. (Remember, the C# 1.0 design team did not know that they would be adding generics in C# 2.0 or generic variance in C# 4.0.)  For the C# 1.0 design team the question was whether `enumValues as int[]` should be legal or not, and they decided not.  Then that design decision was made again for C# 2.0 and C# 4.0.

There are plenty of principled arguments on either side but in practice this situation almost never arises in real world code, and the inconsistency almost never matters, so the lowest-cost choice is to just live with the odd fact that `(IEnumerable<int>)(object)enumValues` is legal but `(IEnumerable<int>)enumValues` is not.

For more on this, see my 2009 article on the subject

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/09/24/why-is-covariance-of-value-typed-arrays-inconsistent/

and this related question:

[Why does my C# array lose type sign information when cast to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178973/why-does-my-c-sharp-array-lose-type-sign-information-when-cast-to-object/1179094#1179094)

Comment: One case where the optimisation trips up is `enumValues.Cast<StringComparison>().ToArray()` which would fail with `ArrayTypeMismatchException` while `enumValues.Cast<StringComparison>().Skip(0).ToArray()` would succeed because the optimisation in `Cast<TResult>` then means that an optimisation in `ToArray()` that uses `Array.CopyTo()` throws because it requires a tighter match than `Cast()` produced. (Except in .NET Core where the restrictions on `Array.CopyTo()` were loosened to allow this).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a class `Car` and a derived car: `Volvo`.

```
Car car = new Volvo();
var type = car.GetType();
```

Although you casted the`Volvo` to a `Car`, the object is still a `Volvo`. If you ask for its type, you would get that it is a `typeof(Volvo)`.

`Enumerable.Cast<TResult>` will cast every element of the input sequence to a `TResult`, but they are still your original objects. Hence your sequence of Foos are still Foos, even after you cast them to integers.

### Addition after comments

Several people commented that this is not the case with IEnumerable.Cast. I thought that would be strange, but let's give it a try:

```
class Car
{
    public string LicensePlate {get; set;}
    public Color Color {get; set;}
    ...
}
class Volvo : Car
{
    public string OriginalCountry => "Sverige";
}
```

usage:

```
var volvos = new List<Volvo>() {new Volvo(), new Volvo(), new Volvo()};
var cars = volvos.Cast<Car>();
foreach (var car in cars) Console.WriteLine(car.GetType());
```

Result:

```
CarTest.Volvo
CarTest.Volvo
CarTest.Volvo
```

**Conclusion:** Enumerable.Cast does not change the type of the object

Comment: That's not applicable to the case of an array of an enum type being cast to an array of int.

Comment: Nor to the optimisation `Cast<TResult>` takes.