# Why does unboxing array to an incorrect type not throw an exception in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, unboxing

There is a weird inconsistency with converting and unboxing values and arrays:

```
var us = new uint[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var i1 = (int)us[0];                 // direct value to value: works
var i2 = (int)(object)us[0];         // unboxing value to value: compiles, throws at runtime
var is1 = (int[])u;                  // direct array to array: does not compile
var is2 = (int[])(object)u;          // unboxing array to array: works!

is2.GetType().Name                   // UInt32[]
```

Why is array unboxing allowed, when a direct conversion is prohibited?

Comment: It's basically a difference between what the C# language rules permit and what the CLR permits. It's an unfortunate impedence mismatch :(

Comment: it is not a `uint` is larger than an `int` therefore it should not work, because at the moment the compiler doesnt have the value of each member

Comment: Agree with @JonSkeet. Note that you can give a worse example. Like, change the definition of `us` into `new unit[] { 3000000001u, 3000000002u, 3000000003u }` (the numbers chosen being between `2**31` and `2**32` so that they are OK for a 32-bit integer with no sign, but too large for a 32-bit _signed_ integer).

Comment: Also try reading [Why does "int&#91;&#93; is uint&#91;&#93; == true" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593730/), and other threads, to see related surprises also originating from the unfortunate issue that the C# language and the .NET runtime do not agree on whether an `int[]` and a `uint[]` are compatible or not.

Comment: Attempt better link: [Why does "int\[\] is uint\[\] == true" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593730/)

Comment: The code with 3-billion-something (my first comment): [online illustration (C# source encoded in URL)](https://tio.run/##jZI9b8IwEIZ3/4prp0QKCST9EKBODFWrtktbdYgymHAFt4mN/BGKEL89vUCjIARSbQ93lu9537Odm16uNNa1M0LO4XVtLJZjxozlVuSQF9wYmMCm3aiUmMEzF9LzaZNVXIMzcAcSV@CEtGkGG0j6f2Pggi6JD5PEwZZkoqghiAERPKr2nUn72RjOjSiCmdCYW6h44RCs2gcjWCn9bVpc3OI8Nf2i0@ewhHNyqn6azo@BuSqXokATgF1otTLALWgnrSixlTGt7TQjhf@45lrzdSOyC0YwU2hAKtuqsT037rhdByfta/xEjTJHekVZoT6W2Jl380UjUCoJU26oyfWyvbELxiZKGlVg@KGFxSch0SMD4T3aNzrm@eELL9Efd5LvD9ImcZqdKDRW01WGj4q@x2UAtAjl74qpsDeIh1fDm9t4eB0cJFeHScLYlmZd/wI)

Comment: Another good thread about these problems: [Why does my C# array lose type sign information when cast to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178973/) Also note that instead of `(object)` you can use other types that both `int[]` and `unit[]` are, for example you could do `(int[])(System.Array)us` and `(int[])(System.ICloneable)us` and so on. Finally note that an array of value types is not itself a value type, it is a reference type; therefore technically the word _unboxing_ is not correct when it comes to conversions from `object` etc. to `int[]`. It is a reference conversion.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is array unboxing allowed, when a direct conversion is prohibited?

If you do `(int[])(object)us`, you are doing two conversions, [both of which are allowed by C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#explicit-reference-conversions):

- from `uint[]` to `object` (you are allowed to cast any reference type to `object`)
- from `object` to `int[]` (you are allowed to cast from `object` to any reference type)

Therefore `(int[])(object)us` compiles.

If you do `(int[])us`, you are doing a single conversion from `int[]` to `uint[]`, which is not allowed by C#. According to the C# spec, you can only cast from a `T[]` to `U[]` if `T` and `U` are reference types, and that you can cast from `T` to `U`. `int` and `uint` satisfy neither of those, so `(int[])us` does not compile.

At runtime, the cast from `uint[]` to `int[]` is checked to see if it succeeds or fails. The CLR does allow this. See section I.8.7.1 of the [CLR spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-335/).

> A signature type T is compatible-with a signature type U if and only if at least one of the following holds.
>
> [...]
>
> T is an array with rank r and element type V, and U is an array with the same rank r and element type W, and V is array-element-compatible-with W.
>
> [...]
>
> A signature type T is array-element-compatible-with a signature type U if and only if T has underlying type V and U has underlying type W and either:
>
> 1. V is compatible-with W; or
> 2. V and W have the same reduced type.

And the "reduced types" of `int` and `uint` are both `int`.

This is why `(int[])(object)us` succeeds at runtime.

Also note that casting `us` to `object` is not "boxing". Everything is a reference type here. You're just changing the type of the reference.

Comment: You can use a method like the following to (down)cast a reference to an array type without allowing the following situations: (A) the run-time type and the type being cast to are array types of integers, but one is signed and the other is unsigned. (B) The two types involves an integer type and an enum type, or two distinct enum types. (C) The cast would be valid only by the **pathological array covariance** of C# and the runtime (the array covariance is "pathological" because arrays are read-write, not read-only, so the covariance is not sound). Here:

Comment: `static T[] PedanticDowncastToArray<T>(object obj)
{
if (obj is T[] arr && arr.GetType() == typeof(T[]))
{
return arr;
}
throw new ArgumentException($"The argument '{obj}' is not precisely an instance of a one-dimensional array with element type '{typeof(T)}'.", nameof(obj));
}
}`