# Unexpected operator is/as behavior when casting an int[] to object

Tags: c#

Could someone please explain why this is happening?

```
var y = new int[]{1,2};

Console.WriteLine(y is uint[]); // false
Console.WriteLine(((object)y) is uint[]); // true
```

Comment: Kinda dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593730/why-does-int-is-uint-true-in-c-sharp

Comment: I believe the first should generate a compiler warning [Indeed it does *expression is never of the provided uint[] type*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In c# you can't cast an `int` to a `uint`, so the first test fails because it is compiled to constant false.

However, int->uint cast **is** allowed by the CLR. The second check cannot be deduced by the compiler and therefore must be calculated at runtime. As you've dodged compiler checks, the CLR allows it.