# How to use IEnumerable.Cast<> and .ToArray() to convert int array to an enum array?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

Consider the following enum declaration and int array:

```
enum Test { None };

int[] data = {0};
```

To convert this `int[]` array to an `Test[]` array we can simply do this:

```
Test[] result = Array.ConvertAll(data, element => (Test)element);
```

I initially tried to do this:

```
Test[] result = data.Cast<Test>().ToArray();
```

However, that throws an exception at runtime:

> System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Source array type cannot be assigned to destination array type.

**Question One**

Is there a way to do this using Linq and `Cast<>` without an error, or must I just use `Array.Convert()`?

**Question Two** (added after the first question was answered correctly)

Exactly why doesn't it work?

It seems like it's a case of an implementation detail escaping... Consider:

This causes an error:

```
var result = data.Cast<Test>().ToList(); // Happens with "ToList()" too.
```

But this does not:

```
var result = new List<Test>();

foreach (var item in data.Cast<Test>())
    result.Add(item);
```

And neither does this:

```
var result = data.Select(x => x).Cast<Test>().ToList();
```

The clear implication is that some kind of optimisation is being done in the `.ToList()` implementation that causes this exception.

---

Addendum:

This also works:

```
List<int> data = new List<int>{0};
var result = data.Cast<Test>().ToList();
```

or

```
List<int> data = new List<int>{0};
var result = data.Cast<Test>().ToArray();
```

It's only if the original data is an array that it doesn't work.

Comment: Why? `Array.ConvertAll` works and is more efficient

Comment: @TimSchmelter I guess it's really an academic question.

Comment: And now I've become quite interested in why it doesn't work... :)

Comment: actually `Cast<T>` and my answer are roughly equivalent: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,152b93d25e224365

Comment: @DanielA.White Except yours works and Cast<> doesn't!

Comment: what version of .net are you using?

Comment: @DanielA.White 4.5.2

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WukXhC confirmed in .net 4.5

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't think the answer is there, I think it's some internal optimisation to avoid copying arrays - if the source collection is an array it fails but if it's a list it works!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `.Select(e => (Test)e)`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work in this case because `Cast` first performs the following check:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
{
  IEnumerable<TResult> results = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
  if (results != null)
    return results;
  // ... the rest of the method
}
```

It turns out that for `int[]` this check succeeds (so `int[]` as `IEnumerable<Test>` is not null). In result, `Cast` actually does nothing at all, it returns array as is. Then when you call `ToArray`, `Array.Copy` is invoked. It tries to copy from `int[]` array to `Test[]` array, and fails because of type mismatch. This exception you see.

Comment: So this does actually look like a bug in the implementation to me.

Comment: @MatthewWatson not really, the reason is described here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/593799/5311735. In short, C# and CLR have somewhat different approaches about casting arrays of different numeric types. Here is the same story, because enum is basically just a number. You cannot cast int[] to IEnumerable<Test> (or Test[]) - compiler won't allow you because it thinks there is no such converstion. But CLR allows that and in runtime this actually happens.

Answer (score 1):

Because the cast actually did not do anything since it thinks that the collection is already the desire type

```
    IEnumerable<Test> cast = data.Cast<Test>();
    IEnumerable<Test> select = data.Select(e => (Test) e);

    Console.WriteLine(cast == (IEnumerable<int>) data); //True
    Console.WriteLine(select == (IEnumerable<int>) data); //False
    Console.WriteLine(select == cast); //Flase
```

as you can see the cast `IEnumerable` is actually just the original array. Thus `.ToArray` is trying to do something similar to `(Test[]) data.ToArray();`

Comment: Which would be a bug in the implementation, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MatthewWatson from my point of view, yes

Comment: @matthew: depends, the Cast method is not the cast operator. Its more strict. So don't use it in this way. You are trying to convert an int[] to an Test[]. That's a conversion. There's already a meaningful and efficient conversion method in the Array class which works

Comment: @TimSchmelter That can't be significant because it works fine if the source is a `List<>` - it only fails if the source is an array. (Turns out, this is a small bug in .Net)