# Given Array.Cast<T>(), how do I determine T via reflection?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

TL;DR - I would expect these all to work the same, but (per comments) they do not:

```
var c1 = new[] { FileMode.Append }.Cast<int>();
var c2 = new[] { FileMode.Append }.Select(x => (int)x);
var c3 = new[] { FileMode.Append }.Select(x => x).Cast<int>();

foreach (var x in c1 as IEnumerable)
  Console.WriteLine(x); // Append (I would expect 6 here!)

foreach (var x in c2 as IEnumerable)
  Console.WriteLine(x); // 6

foreach (var x in c3 as IEnumerable)
  Console.WriteLine(x); // 6
```

This is a contrived example; I obviously wouldn't cast the collections to `IEnumerable` if I didn't have to, and in that case everything would work as expected. But I'm working on a library with several methods that take an `object` and return a serialized string representation. If it determines via reflection that the object implements `IEnumerable`, it will enumerate it and, in almost all cases, return the expected result...except for this strange case with `Array.Cast<T>`.

There's 2 things I could do here:

1. Tell uses to materialize `IEnumerable`s first, such as with `ToList()`.
2. Create an overload for each affected method that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`.

For different reasons, neither of those is ideal. Is it possible for a method that takes an `object` to somehow infer `T` when `Array.Cast<T>()` is passed?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41169272/3791245) for a peek at the source of `IEnumerable.Cast<T>`.  In this particular use case, `Cast<T>` just returns the original array as it was - of type `FileMode` and not of type `int`.  (It's not really casting anything, since this particular enum was implemented as an int.)

Comment: If you're dealing with an `IEnumerable` then you'd want to do `foreach(int x in whatever)` to get the desired casting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible for a method that takes an object to somehow infer T when Array.Cast() is passed?

No, not in the example you gave.

The reason you get the output you do is that the [`Enumerable.Cast<T>()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,27bb217a6d5457ec) method has an optimization to allow the original object to be returned when it's compatible with the type you ask for:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source) {
    IEnumerable<TResult> typedSource = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
    if (typedSource != null) return typedSource;
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    return CastIterator<TResult>(source);
}
```

So in your first case, nothing actually happens. The `Cast<T>()` method is just returning the object you passed into the method, and so by the time you get it back, the fact that it ever went through `Cast<T>()` is completely lost.

Your question doesn't have any other details about how you got into this situation or why it matters in a practical sense. But we can say conclusively that given the code you posted, it would be impossible to achieve the goal you've stated.

Comment: Thanks, glad to confirm I'm not going crazy at least. Context/background for this question is [here](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/632) if you're curious. Unless I introduce `IEnumerable<T>` overloads I'll likely have to close it as a "won't fix". :)

Comment: I still find it interesting that in my original example, c1 and c3 behave differently. But I verified that while you can cast `FileMode[]` to `IEnumerable<int>`, do `Select(x => x)` on it first and you can't. Counterintuitive, but it does explain it.

Comment: _"do Select(x => x) on it first and you can't"_ -- that's because, while you can look at the `x => x` and understand that it's an identity projection, it would be too costly at runtime for the `Select()` method to do the same, so it has no practical way to optimize the identity projection the way that `Cast<T>()` optimizes the cast. `Select()` has no choice but to _always_ return a new iterator that invokes your projection delegate, so the return object is _always_ not the original one.