# Why does typeof(IList<uint>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int[]) return true?

Tags: .net, arrays, reflection, polymorphism

Why do the following assertions fail (`IsAssignableFrom` returns `true`):

`Assert.False(typeof(IList<UInt16>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Int16[]))`
`Assert.False(typeof(IList<Int16>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(UInt16[]))`
`Assert.False(typeof(IList<UInt32>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Int32[]))`
`Assert.False(typeof(IList<Int32>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(UInt32[]))`
`Assert.False(typeof(IList<UInt64>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Int64[]))`
`Assert.False(typeof(IList<Int64>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(UInt64[]))`

I would have expected them to fail (`IsAssignableFrom` should returns `false`) because this results in a compiler error:

```
IList<UInt16> x = new Int16[]{}; // CS0029 Cannot implictly convert ...
IList<Int16> x = new UInt16[]{}; // CS0029 Cannot implictly convert ...
IList<UInt32> x = new Int32[]{}; // CS0029 Cannot implictly convert ...
IList<Int32> x = new UInt32[]{}; // CS0029 Cannot implictly convert ...
IList<UInt64> x = new Int64[]{}; // CS0029 Cannot implictly convert ...
IList<Int64> x = new UInt64[]{}; // CS0029 Cannot implictly convert ...
```

Comment: The last two asserts actually also fail because they are assignable: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6rzXph

Comment: I think the above qualifies as an answer. Where is my 'Flag this comment as Answer' button :-)

Comment: @PeterB: removed the comment and made it an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is assignable because it works if you cast explicitly:

```
IList<UInt16> x = (IList<UInt16>)(IList)new Int16[] { };
```

So you just can't let it cast implictly to the target type.

> why is a cast from `IList` to `List<UInt16>` valid but a cast from `IList`
>   to `IList<UInt32>` invalid?

Before i start to explain it in my words, read [Jon Skeets answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593730/why-does-int-is-uint-true-in-c-sharp/593799#593799):

> You can't directly cast between `int[]` and `uint[]` in C# because the
>   language doesn't believe any conversion is available. However, if you
>   go via object(*or `IList` in my example) the result is up to the CLI.

CLI spec section 8.7

> Signed and unsigned integral primitive types can be assigned to each
>   other; e.g., `int8 := uint8` is valid. For this purpose, `bool` shall be
>   considered compatible with `uint8` and vice versa, which makes bool :=
>   uint8 valid, and vice versa. This is also true for arrays of signed
>   and unsigned integral primitive types of the same size; e.g., `int32[] := uint32[]` is valid.

Comment: In the above example why is a cast from `IList` to `List<UInt16>`  valid but a cast from `IList` to `IList<UInt32>` invalid?