# Class invariant to ensure a particular data type on a field does not hold

Tags: c#, code-contracts, invariants

Given the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

using System;

public class Program
{
    public int[] ints = new int[1000];

  [ContractInvariantMethod]
  private void ObjectInvariant ()
  {
    Contract.Invariant(ints.GetType() == typeof(int[]));
    Contract.Invariant(ints != null);
  }
}
```

Why is the invariant `ints.GetType() == typeof(int[])` considered to cannot be proven? If I change the invariant to `ints.GetType() == ints.GetType()` it passes (without any surpise), but why does it fail for `typeof(int[])`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you can in fact store objects in an `int[]` that aren't actually an `int[]`.  There are some valid conversions that you would hope wouldn't be valid, but that in fact are.  For example, someone could write:

```
ints = (int[])(object)new uint[5];
```

and now the type of `ints` is an unsigned int array, not an int array.  That this conversion is valid is unfortunate (that it's valid almost exclusively just causes bugs when it comes up); it's be great if what you posted *could* be an invariant, but sadly, `Contract.Invariant` is correct that it's not.

Comment: I couldn't believe this first, but you are right. Is this crazy language (or CLR?) feature somewhere documented?

Comment: Then what's the right way to check that elemnts of `ints` are actually of type `int`?

Comment: @KlausGütter Off hand, I believe that the conversion is invalid in the C# type system (hence why it won't compile without the cast to `object`), but valid in the CLR, so the compiler will try to prevent the conversion but the CLR will allow it.

Comment: Thank you. In the meanwhile I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593730/why-does-int-is-uint-true-in-c-sharp where Jon's answer confirms what you say.

Comment: @cristid9 um...you wrote the code to check it.  It just has to be a runtime check, not a compile time check.  Now you can get an item from the array and treat it as an `int`.  It might not behave the way you want (you'd be treating an unsigned int's bits as if it were a signed int, giving you a messed up value) but you can do it.

Comment: @KlausGütter Of course you probably don't *want* to go around checking for this whenever you've got an int array.  You probably just want to assume the int array is an int array, and if someone does something evil like this you just blame them for using your type in an inappropriate way.  Garbage in garbage out and all that.

Comment: Got it working with this one `Contract.Invariant(ints[0] is int);`

Comment: And interestingly `ints[0].GetType()` is typeof(int) even if `ints.GetType()` is typeof(uint[]).

Comment: @cristid9 In that case the code has already converted the `uint` to an `int` when it was returned by the indexer (it just has a mangled value by that point).  Also, what if the array is empty?

Comment: Man, it is a homework, all they ask me is to write an invariant to "Write the object (class) invariants that ensure that arrays represent sets
of Integers." So I think all I need to do is to check if `ints` contains ints and there are no duplicates in the array.

Comment: @cristid9 Sure sounds like a really poorly designed assignment to me (unless there's more to it than you've described).  Probably worth bringing up with your instructor.