# Is is possible to export functions from a C# DLL like in VS C++?

Tags: c#, c++, notepad++, dllexport

In VS C/C++ you could use `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) -function declaration-`.

How do I accomplish this in a C# dll? Is there C# code equivalent to the above code?

**Edit: More info**

I am trying to create an add in for Notepad++ and I want to use C#, but the common way I've seen so far is to use legacy C++ code with the above call to export a few of the functions that Notepad++ expects to import and call. There is an example app using C#, but this still requires a loader DLL, which I assume from the comments/answers below is the only way for C#.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Unmanaged Exports** => 
https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports

**DLLExport** => https://github.com/3F/DllExport

> #### How does it work?
>
> Create a new classlibrary or proceed with an existing one.
>   Then add the UnmanagedExports [Nuget package](https://nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports).
>
> This is pretty much all setup that is required.
>
> Now you can write any kind of static method, decorate it with `[DllExport]` and use it from native code.
>   It works just like DllImport, so you can customize the marshalling of parameters/result with `MarshalAsAttribute`.
>
> During compilation, my task will modify the IL to add the required exports...

Comment: The DllExports project is now on [GitHub](https://github.com/3F/DllExport).

Comment: After downloading the 3F/DllExport example [here](https://github.com/3F/Examples/tree/master/DllExport) and trying to build with VS 2017 CE, the tool does not export functions for some reason. Hoping [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71441509/why-is-dllexport-not-exporting-functions-in-3f-dllexport-example-using-vs-2017-c) might lead to a solution.

Comment: I wish I had seen this before I went to the pain of creating this for myself using CLR hosting.

Answer (score 20):

I've seen people do this before, but it required ildasm, adding the MSIL `.export` directive, and then reassembling.  [A program named `dll_tool`](http://winch.pinkbile.com/wiki/index.php/Main/Dlltool) can do these steps for you.

If you want to build a mixed-mode DLL with both native and managed exports, you should be using C++/CLI, which is specially designed for this purpose.

Comment: do you have a small github demo project to support this, or perhaps know of some?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible to export functions from a C# dll in much the same way that C++ does it! You need a little help from an add-in [Unmanaged Exports (DllExport for .Net)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports) that facilitates this process, or from a similar method such as [Exporting functions in C#/VB.NET to native code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439223/Exporting-functions-in-Csharp-VB-NET-to-native-cod).

Please see [Code to Export C# DLL to Metatrader Build 600+](http://vb6-to-csharp.blogspot.com/2014/05/code-to-export-c-dll-to-metatrader.html) for a working example using Robert Giesecke's C# Project Template for Unmanaged Exports to export a C# dll to a legacy application (Metatrader) that has a great deal of similarity to C++.

Additionally, you might find [Native and .NET Interopability](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports) interesting though it is mostly geared toward accessing native code from within .NET rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do that in the same sense as you do in C and C++.

But you can create COM API to achieve that which then you can use in C and C++ code.

See these articles

- [C# Classes as COM Objects](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/05/c-classes-as-com-objects/)
- [Calling Managed .NET C# COM Objects from Unmanaged C++ Code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ManagedCOM.aspx)
- [COM Interop Part 1: C# Client Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There's now an open source package called **DNNE** aka "Native Exports for .NET" available here: https://github.com/AaronRobinsonMSFT/DNNE

As for today, it' requires .NET6 installed, but it does support exporting .NET Framework 4.8 .dll functions as well.