# create header file (.h) and .lib file in visual c#

Tags: c#, dll

I want to create a dll in visual c#, and use it in win32 program (visual c++).
From what I understand, for adding dll file in Visual C++ , I need also .h file and .lib file, but when I create a class library in visual c# I only get dll file.
Is it possible to create a .h file and .lib file in visual c# ?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818850/is-is-possible-to-export-functions-from-a-c-sharp-dll-like-in-vs-c

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not possible. But [here](http://1code.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Invoke%20.NET%20Assembly%20from%20Native%20C%2b%2b#CLIWrapper) is what you can do to use a C# library in C++:

1. C++/CLI Wrapper (this allows you to have both managed and unmanaged code in the same source file. The managed portion can then call the C# code). [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Consuming-C-Library-in-937458e5) you can find an example.
2. Host CLR (the CLR acts as a library that can be loaded and "hosted" by a process).
3. COM Interop (expose your .NET type as a COM interface and matching coclass which you can easily use from unmanaged C++).

[This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/299da822-5539-4e5b-9ba7-b614e564c9f4/) is also quite interesting!

Comment: I'm trying the first solution, I use a version of Visual Studio Express, can I create an empty solution?

Comment: What do you mean with "empty solution"?

Comment: this what written [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Consuming-C-Library-in-937458e5) Step 1. Create a empty solution.

Comment: Well just create a simple library project for a simple C# library. That's what he means.

Comment: if I will do it in visual c#, how will I create a C++ project in visual c#?

Comment: Well just stick on that guideline, it should do the job for you. You have to choose a C++ project type from the list of available projects types when you select to create a new project in VS: Templates -> Visual C# -> Class Library.

Comment: I think you do not know the Express version

Answer (score 0):

You could use **LoadLibrary** and **GetProcAddress** to load the DLL dynamically and you wouldn't need to create the files you refer to. You can [read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686944%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: This way can you also create instances of a class defined in the dll?