# Passing objects between C# library and C++ (CLR)

Tags: c#, c++, clr, unmanaged, unmanaged-memory

How to pass objects from C# library to C++.

I can call a function which returns `void` or `int`  without any issue.

Now consider the following function in C#,

```
List<CSharpClass> CSharpFunction(string Input)
```

where my C# class contains,

```
public class CSharpClass
{ 
    string mystring = string.Empty;
    byte[] bytearray = null;        

    public byte[] bytearray 
    {
        get { return bytearray ; }
        set { bytearray = value; }
    }

    public string mystring 
    {
        get { return mystring ; }
        set { mystring = value; }
    }      
}
```

Now, I want use this List in my C++. So I have created,

```
  typedef std::vector<class CSharpClass>  MyDetailList;
```

Is it the right way ?? If not what I need to use in C++?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to call a C# dll from C++ code, you can follow [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736).
In a nutshell, you're going to have to:
- Write a Managed DLL containing your CSharpClass
- Register the Managed DLL for Use with COM or with Native C++
- Call the Managed DLL from Native C++ Code

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144006/using-c-sharp-dll-in-c-code) is also relevant, and contains alternative solutions if you want to avoid using COM

---

Initial misguided answer:

You can check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/552348/C-23-2fCplusinteroppluswithplusDllImport) for a fairly good tutorial.
In a nutshell, you're going to have to:
- Compile a dll from your c++ code
- marshall ("translate") your class between C# and C++
- load the dll from C#, by using DllImport declaration
- call the imported method

Comment: I've C# dll, want to get the byte[] in C++ project. As I have mentioned, I can call a function which returns void or int without any issue.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I misread the question. Will edit answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks for updated answer, but I couldn't find any answer to get the byte[] in C++ project :(