# How to transfer byte[] from C# to char buffer in C/ C++?

Tags: c++, char, byte, arrays, clr

I have `byte[]` in C#. I want to pass this value to C++ (CLR). How to do it ?

I have tried converting the `byte[][]` to `char[][]` in C#.

Now Is it possible to use this char** variable in C++? If it is not, what I need to use ?

**EDIT:**

I want the output in character buffer in C++ code.

My Existing code can be found at [Passing objects between C# library and C++ (CLR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719142/passing-objects-between-c-sharp-library-and-c-clr/21719310)

Comment: `char[][]` is not the same as `char**`. `char**` is a pointer to a pointer while `char[][]` is an array of `char`. ( Which is similar to a pointer in most aspects. ) Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string

Comment: @olevegard I do understand the concepts, but how to transfer byte[] from C# to C++?

Comment: Is this C++ calling C# or C# calling C++?

Comment: @cup c# returns byte[] I want to use it in C++

Comment: What is your method of interprocess communications?

Comment: @DavidO Please check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719142/passing-objects-between-c-sharp-library-and-c-clr/21719310