# Compile C# .dll and produce .dll and .lib file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, .lib

I have create a class library project at Visual studio with C#. While i am debugging library project a .dll file appears in my bin project folder.I would like to know if is any possible way to produce from the same project a .lib file too.

Comment: See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t98ax4.aspx.  dll, exe, and lib are created from the intermediate .obj files.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What is your end goal? What are you going to use this LIB file for?

Comment: @jdweng in the case of a Win32/C++ project, yes. This question is tagged and titled with C#.

Comment: @CodeCaster i would like to use my .lib to another c++ project for tests.

Comment: Then [Using C# dll in C++ code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144006/using-c-sharp-dll-in-c-code) is relevant. It's not as simple as exposing a LIB file, as a .NET DLL isn't really a Win32 DLL. Well it is, but not in the way it exports CLR types and methods.

Comment: C# does not create libs.

Comment: See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx.  Not sure why libs can't be created from obj in c#,  Maybe it just the options provided in vs. Doesn't mean the command line compile won't work.