# How to ger method of class from a loaded C# dl-library in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

I'm trying to get method of class from a loaded C# dl-library in C++

Main program (C++):

```
HINSTANCE hMyDLL = LoadLibrary(L"ClassLibrary1.dll");
if (NULL == hMyDLL) {
  std::cout << "LoadLibrary failed\n";
  getchar();
  return -1;
}

typedef int (WINAPI * function) ();
function f = (function)GetProcAddress(hMyDLL, "Class1.test");
if (NULL == f) {
  std::cout << ":(\n";
}
```

DLL code (C#):

```
namespace ClassLibrary1 {
    public class Class1 {
        public static int test()  {
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

How can i get method **test** of class **Class1**?

Comment: See also this duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/q/19144006/416574

Comment: Now that you know UnmanagedExports you can search for many more duplicates