# Call .Net Function Using Addresses

Tags: c#

I trying to call .NET function from native code and via virtual address.
I wrote a simple class library that have a class and static method and I browse with [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy)

I also checked ImageBase value is 0x10000000

```
using System;

// Token: 0x02000002 RID: 2
public class Class1 : object
{
    // Token: 0x06000001 RID: 1 RVA: 0x00002050 File Offset: 0x00000250
    public static int Calculate(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

I'm looking at the documentation of [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) which says:

> Loads the specified module into the address space of the calling
>   process.

When I call calculate function, I'm getting AV Error.

Exception thrown at 0x10002050 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x10002050. occurred

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef int(*Calculate)(int x, int y);

PVOID RvaToVa(PVOID rva, PVOID imageBase)
{
    return PVOID((int)rva + (int)imageBase);
}

int main()
{
    HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(L"ClassLibrary1.dll");
    if (!hModule)
    {
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    PVOID fPtr = RvaToVa((PVOID)0x00002050, (PVOID)0x10000000);
    Calculate calculate = (Calculate)fPtr;

    if (calculate)
    {
        int result = calculate(31, 32);
        cout << result << endl;
    }
    FreeLibrary(hModule);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to load & initialize the CLR.

Comment: An Assembly (compiled C# library into `.dll` file) is not native code, is compiled into an intermediate language. You cannot execute it without the runtime (CLR).

Comment: Clever attempt, but I agree with the previous comments.  Impossible, unless you are targeting a normal WINAPI, STDCALL or CDECL DLL (AND its dependency DLLs are available), not a DLL that requires a runtime Engine

Comment: You can use the unmanaged export library to do that or export the class as an ActiveX component. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4818850/2557263

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro  I know unmanaged export library.